# How to query on parse json object child value if it contains/equal to/greater than etc.?

Tags: java, android, json, parse-platform, back4app

I have a table in parse server (back4app) as below.

```
[{
  "companyName":"Abc Ltd",
  "branchAddress":"1-1,Xyz Street",
  "empInfo":
       {"name":"Naveen",
        "age":25,
        "salary":35000}
},
{
  "companyName":"Abc Ltd",
  "branchAddress":"123, Mno Street",
  "empInfo":
       {"name":"Some Other Person",
        "age":29,
        "salary":45000}
}
//Other Elements]
```

I want to get the elements who's salary is greater than certain amount !

`empInfo` is a `JSONObject`

**I didnt find any query on JSONObject in official docs.**

I hope I can find help here. Thank you.

Comment: Post the *code* you tried here.

Comment: I didnt tried because there is no information regarding query on JSONObject !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```java
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("MyClass");
query.whereGreaterThan("empInfo.salary", 1000);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objs, ParseException e) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you bro ! Let me try and get back to you !